# Flexagons - where to learn the theory behind them?

Tags: reference-request

The subject says it all! A friend of mine introduced me to these cool objects made of paper strips, and I was wondering if anyone could point me to any resources (ideally freely accessible) to learn more about the mathematical theory behind them.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexagon#Bibliography) .

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did not realize there was a wikipedia page devoted to them. Should I delete my question? Or maybe you should post your comment as an answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: Dont forget to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexagon#External_links) either.